# text file not embedded into HTML when sending email via Python

Tags: python, html, mime, smtplib

I have this python code using MIME to send a receipt on a gmail server.

```
email["Subject"] = "Your PetShop reciept"
    email["From"] = sender
    email["To"] = reciever 
    
    plain = f"""\
    Hi {name}, thank you for shopping with us!
    Below is your eReciept:
    {reciept}
    
    We hope you have a lovely day!
    ----------------------------------------------
    If you are having trouble viewing this message
    please contact our customer service helpline:
    12334
"""
    
    html = f"""
<html>
    
    <body style="background-color:#33476c">
        <h1 style="font-family:Arial">Hi {name}, thanks for shopping with us!</h1>
        <h3 style="font-family:Arial">Below is your eReciept:</h3>
        <br>
        </br>
        <object data="hi.txt" type="text/plain"
            width="500" style="height: 300px">
        <a href="hi.txt">No Support?</a>
        </object>
        <p style="font-size:24px">------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</p>
        <p style="font-size:14px">If you are having issues accessing this email,
        please feel free to call our customer service helpline 12344</p>
    </body>
</html>"""
    part1 = MIMEText(plain,"plain")
    part2 = MIMEText(html,"html")
    
    email.attach(part1)
    email.attach(part2)
```

But the text file that I want to embed into my html doesn't show up in the email. Everything else does but the text file doesn't. What should I do? The text file is in the same directory as my python file.

Comment: It looks normal to me, you are sending a multipart mail. By default the mail "client" (Gmail ?) will show HTML, if it is capable of rendering HTML, and otherwise fall back on the text version (which would be the behavior of a rudimentary mail client). Thus you are seeing either HTML or text (worst case) - not both. Look at the source code of the received mail, both versions should be visible in the raw source. What you could do though, is send the text version along as **attachment** and not inline.

Answer (score 0):

Had this same problem once.

I had to attach the file:

```
# open the file to be sent  
file = "name_of_file_with_extension"
attachment = open("Path to the file", "rb") 

# create mimebase instance
payload = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream') 
payload.set_payload((attachment).read()) 
encoders.encode_base64(payload) 
payload.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % file) 
email.attach(p)
```